# How to get access to Quote PDF from backend

Tags: pdf, quote

on Quote page we have list of PDF generated for the current quote. 
Is there any mechanism I could have access to pdf files from apex class? (I mean from backend).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuoteDocument is the object that you can use to reference those PDF's.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_quotedocument.htm

Comment: sfdcJameson, unfortunately I don't see any method to enumerate PDF's or so. Do you have any example?

Comment: Are you a developer? If you are, a quick google search should point you in the right direction now that you know which object those PDFs are stored in.

Comment: sfdcJameson, you absolutely right - google is the best. We googled this issue before this question was posted here. Also we googled after your response, unfortunately found nothing useful. We are beginners in apex, so if you could post here any link or example - I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I finally realized that QuoteDocument is the object which contains binary data for PDF. Thank you.